# Remove rendered image from page with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on designing a modal where the user can upload multiple images at a time from their system, and have them displayed in the pop-up modal. One of the requirements is to add a functionality where the user can hit a button to delete all rendered images that were uploaded.. My reset button currently just clears the information, but does not delete the image. Does anybody have any ideas? My HTML, CSS and JS are all below:

In future, I will need to change this to be able to allow a user to call an API which gets images from an AWS S3 server to then render back to the screen... not sure if vanilla JS is the best for this? We are limited to using only HTML, CSS, and JS.

```js
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var image = new Image();

        //styling in JS //
        image.height = 160;
        image.width = 160;
        image.style.flexDirection = "row";

        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;

        preview.appendChild(image);

      }, false);


      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }
}
```

```css
/* floating buttons: */

.floating-btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0B406D;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: fixed;
  right: 120px;
  bottom: 20px;
  outline: blue;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-btn:hover {
  background: #4D89C8;
}

.floating-btn2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0B406D;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  outline: blue;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-btn2:hover {
  background: #4D89C8;
}


/*Modal styling: */

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  displ
```

```html
<!--Modal code: -->
<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
      <h2>Image search and processing: </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form id="modal-form" class="form">
        <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
        <input id="files" target="_blank" type="file" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple/>
        <output id="result">
        <button type="submit" class="floating-btn" value ="submit">+</button>
        <button type="reset" class="floating-btn2" value ="reset" onclick="return hideImage()">x</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="preview"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the delete button function ?

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove that because it didn't work haha. I followed something like:

function hideImage(){
  var remove = document.querySelector("reset");
  remove.removeChild(remove.childNodes[0]);
}

Comment: You want to clear / hide images one by one or all in one by clicking the `X` button ?

Comment: I think it should clear everything rather than one by one.. I will need some sort of implementation to get rid of specific images that the user clicks, but that might be a problem for later. This functionality is to present a bunch of images on a modal so that they can be approved for processing and added to a training model.

Comment: but yes, the x button should clear everything.. sorry I'm being so vague! I'm at a loss and hit a brick wall after being stuck for a few days

Comment: Everything ? you only have images in your form ? what else you have ?

Comment: sorry, it will only hold images!

Comment: user uploads images
images are rendered and displayed in modal
buttons either send them to be processed or clear the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) function to `clear / reset` your form after the `images` are uploaded or previewed and use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) you clear the `preview` of the your images by clicking `hideImage()` or press `X` button

**Live Demo:**

```js
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var image = new Image();

        //styling in JS //
        image.height = 160;
        image.width = 160;
        image.style.flexDirection = "row";

        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;

        preview.appendChild(image);

      }, false);


      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }
}

function hideImage() {
  document.getElementById("modal-form").reset(); //reset form
  var preview = document.querySelector("#preview");
  preview.innerHTML = '' //set preview to null
}
```

```css
.floating-btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0B406D;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: fixed;
  right: 120px;
  bottom: 20px;
  outline: blue;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-btn:hover {
  background: #4D89C8;
}

.floating-btn2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0B406D;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  outline: blue;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-btn2:hover {
  background: #4D89C8;
}


/*Modal styling: */

.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20% auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  animation-name: modalopen;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.modal-header {
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: black;
}

.modal-header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-body {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.closeBtn {
  color: #ccc;
  float: right;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.closeBtn:hover,
.closeBtn:focus {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes modalopen {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/*Image displaying style: */

form {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id="modal-form" class="form">
  <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
  <input id="files" target="_blank" type="file" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple />
  <div id="result">
    <button type="submit" class="floating-btn" value="submit">+</button>
    <button type="reset" class="floating-btn2" value="reset" onclick="return hideImage()">x</button>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: We'll see! Will probably post more questions later if I get stuck (front-end design ain't my bag...) Thanks again :)